# Reporting feature in Gitlab

Tags: git, reporting, gitlab

Is there any reporting feature in Gitlab which gives below details:

> - Developer who has raised merged request
> - Merge Request Number
> - Status of Merge request
> - Number of check-ins which are part of the merge request
> - Number of comments
> - Number of comments addressed
> - List of comments
> - List of comments responses

These details are needed to do a kind of analysis and provide the report to our client.

Looking for a way where manual analysis can be avoided. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Looking for a way where manual analysis can be avoided

Since git has so many features and flags no GUI can support it. Too many options and promotions.

Due to that GUI tools only support a tiny set of command/flags.

In your case its much better to do it manually with a script which will also give you a better control on the result.